# Storyboard Segue Transition Effects

Tags: ios, xcode, uistoryboard, uistoryboardsegue

First time poster, long time observer.

I am using storyboards for an app I am working on at present, and require more of a transition than just going forward, for going back in particular. Whenever i use this segue i have for going back through a menu, the next button that is clicked on to go to another ViewController, will crash the whole app!

No idea whats going on, i am using this in the implementation file

```
#import "SlideLeftSegue.h"

@implementation SlideLeftSegue

- (void)perform{
    UIView *sv = ((UIViewController *)self.sourceViewController).view;
    UIView *dv = ((UIViewController *)self.destinationViewController).view;

    UIWindow *window = [[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] window];
    dv.center = CGPointMake(sv.center.x - sv.frame.size.width, dv.center.y);
    [window insertSubview:dv belowSubview:sv];

    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.4
                     animations:^{
                         dv.center = CGPointMake(sv.center.x,
                                                 dv.center.y);
                         sv.center = CGPointMake(sv.center.x + sv.frame.size.width,
                                                 dv.center.y);
                     }
                     completion:^(BOOL finished){
                         [[self destinationViewController]
                          dismissViewControllerAnimated:NO completion:nil];
                     }];
}

@end
```

This is my header file

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

//  Move to the previous screen with slide animation.

@interface SlideLeftSegue : UIStoryboardSegue

@end
```

I am still learning, so if you have any idea whats happening, id appreciate an explanation at a beginner level.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can achieve that with less code

To present a view controller:

```
UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
UIViewController *view = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ViewID"];
view.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCoverVertical; // you can try the other 3 UIModalTransitionStyle too
[self presentViewController:view animated:YES completion:nil];
```

To go back:

```
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
```

Comment: I did that and this is what it spat back at me.

No visible @interface for 'SlideLeftSegue' declares the selector 'dismissViewControllerAnimated:completion:'

Comment: FYI, when it crashes from trying to move between screens using the SlideLeftSegue, it says 
"Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=EXC_I386_GPFLT)"

Comment: What I understood is, you're trying to represent views by pressing some sort of buttons. In storyboard, why don't you set up a button in your source view controller and then connect your button with Command-drag to your destination view. After that, to go back to your source VC, use the code above.

Comment: Yeah, say I have VC1 and VC2. On VC1 i have a button that i command-dragged to VC2, and the segue is push. On VC2 i have a button that i command-dragged to VC1 and set the segue as custom, SlideLeftSegue. Im not sure what I'm doing wrong because this left segue isn't working for me.

Comment: Ok, try this: cancel the second segue, and change the "push" in segue 1 to "modal". I'm sending an example project in a moment.

Comment: Thanks, Thats great, i will look into it.
Am i correct in saying that for each view controller i need to manually setup their .m &.h files, set the forward segue to modal, and then for the return segue link the button to
'- (IBAction)dismissView:(UIButton *)sender {
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:NO completion:nil];
}'
and it will behave as I'm trying to have it do?

Comment: Exactly. You could also perform that programmatically too. To do that, first you need to give every view controller an ID in Identity Inspector. I'm gonna add the code into the answer.